# How to use Angular factory data throughout the project

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angular-factory

I have an Angular js `factory`. In which I am storing the user information after successful login. Now I have multiple `controllers` in all of them I need this user information so I need to `inject` this factory to each and every `controller`. Is there any way to access this `factory` data throughout the project without injecting in each and every controller?

Can we directly `inject` it into the `module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some suggestions :**

- storing the user information in factory is not a good approach because if user reload the page it will reset the factory data and user will not exist anymore.
- As [**sajeetharan**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan) suggested, you can use HTML5 `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to store the user information. So, that without injecting you can easily access stored storage value everywhere you want.
- Yes, if you need the user information so you need to inject the factory to each and every controller because on switching from one controller to another controller you have to fetch the data from the factory.If you inject the factory only in the main module it will not load the factory when you move from success login to some other page.

Answer (score 0):

User information can be stored in [`local storage`](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) or cookie so that i can be accessed anywhere.

You can also consider using [**`$rootScope`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope), in that case also you need to inject in all the modules which you require.

Answer (score -2):

a factory is part of a module.
Injecting it into the controllers needed is the way of using the saved values throughout the module.